# Atualização de dados no banco refresh component angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular-material

Queria saber como eu faço pra que toda vez que atualize os dados no banco ele atualize o component no angular ou de refresh na pagina, ou melhor que o serviço seja em tempo real.

Eu já vi varias perguntas, até encontrei algumas, mas era para atualizar o componente com os dados adicionador pelo usuario.

O que eu quero saber, é: como fazer para o banco de dados fazer uma atualização e todos que estiverem logados tenham seus componentes atualizados com as novas informações.

Esse é meu código, tenho que mudar algo nele? ou mudar algo no app.module.ts? Ou não sei, não sei como começar...

ASP.NET Core 2.2
Estou usando Pomelo Framework 2.2 também
MySql

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

import { Madeira } from '../../../../model/madeiras/madeira';
import { MadeiraService } from '../../../../services/madeiras/madeira.service';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, interval } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'pesquisa-madeira',
  templateUrl: './pesquisa.madeira.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pesquisa.madeira.component.css']
})
export class PesquisaMadeiraComponent implements OnInit {


  //private updateSubscription: Subscription;
  public madeiras: Madeira[];
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'descricao', 'espessura', 'largura', 'comprimento', 'preBenef', 'tipo', 'especie', 'controle', 'imagem', 'editar', 'deletar'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Madeira>();


  ngOnInit() {


    //this.updateSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(
    //  (val) => {

    //    this.updateStats()

    //  });

    this.obterTodosMadeira();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    sessionStorage.removeItem('madeiraSession');



  }


  constructor(private madeiraService: MadeiraService, private router: Router) {




    //this.madeiraService.obterTodosMadeira()
    //  .subscribe(

    //    madeiras => {

    //      this.madeiras = madeiras;

    //    },
    //    e =>{

    //      console.log(e.error);

    //    });


  }

  public obterTodosMadeira() {
    this.madeiraService.obterTodosMadeira()
      .subscribe(

        madeiras => {

          this.madeiras = madeiras;
          this.dataSource.data = madeiras;
          //this.ngOnInit();

        },
        e => {

          console.log(e.error);

        });

  }


  public adicionarMadeira() {

    this.router.navigate(['/madeira']);

  }

  public editar(madeira: Madeira) {

    sessionStorage.setItem('madeiraSession', JSON.stringify(madeira));
    this.router.navigate(['/madeira']);

  }

  public deletar(madeira: Madeira){


    var retorno = confirm("Deseja realmente deletar esse item?");


    if (retorno == true) {

      this.madeiraService.deletar(madeira).subscribe(
        madeiras => {
          this.madeiras = madeiras;
          this.dataSource.data = madeiras;

        },
        e => {
          console.log(e.errors);

        }

      )

    }
  }

  //FILTRO DE TABELA
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }


}
```

Madeira.Service:

```js
    import { Injectable, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Madeira } from '../../model/madeiras/madeira';



    @Injectable({

      providedIn: 'root'

    })
    export class MadeiraService implements OnInit {


      private baseUrl;
      public madeiras: Madeira[];

     constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
     }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.madeiras = [];
      }

      get headers(): HttpHeaders {

        return new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');

      }



      public cadastrar(madeira: Madeira): Observable<Madeira> {

        return this.http.post<Madeira>(this.baseUrl + 'api/madeira', JSON.stringify(madeira), { headers: this.headers });


      }

      public salvar(madeira: Madeira): Observable<Madeira> {

        return this.http.post<Madeira>(this.baseUrl + 'api/madeira/salvar', JSON.stringify(madeira), { headers: this.headers });


      }

      public deletar(madeira: Madeira): Observable<Madeira[]> {

        return this.http.post<Madeira[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/madeira/deletar', JSON.stringify(madeira), { headers: this.headers });

      }

      public obterTodosMadeira(): Observable<Madeira[]> {

        return this.http.get<Madeira[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/madeira');

      }

      public obterMadeira(produtoId: number): Observable<Madeira> {

        return this.http.get<Madeira>(this.baseUrl + 'api/madeira/obter');

      }

      public enviarArquivo(arquivoSelecionado: File): Observable<string> {

        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('arquivoEnviado', arquivoSelecionado, arquivoSelecionado.name);

        return this.http.post<string>(this.baseUrl + 'api/madeira/enviarArquivo', formData);

      }


    }
```

Controller:

```cs
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using SysWas.Domain.Contratos.IMadeiras;
    using SysWas.Domain.Entidades.Madeiras;

    namespace SysWas.Web.Controllers.Madeiras
    {

        [Route("api/[Controller]")]
        public class MadeiraController : Controller
        {

            private readonly IMadeiraRepository _madeiraRepository;

            private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

            private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

            public MadeiraController(IMadeiraRepository madeiraRepository, 
                                     IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
                                     IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
            {

                _madeiraRepository = madeiraRepository;
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
                _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;

            }

            [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult Get()
            {
                try
                {
                    return Json(_madeiraRepository.ObterTodos());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
                }


            }

            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Madeira madeira)
            {
                try
                {
                    madeira.Validate();
                    if (!madeira.isValidate) {

                        return BadRequest(madeira.GetMessageValidation());

                    }
                    if(madeira.Id > 0)
                    {

                        _madeiraRepository.Atualizar(madeira);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        madeira.Tipo = null;
                        madeira.Especie = null;
                        madeira.Controle = null;

                        _madeiraRepository.Adicionar(madeira);
                    }

                    return Created("api/madeira", madeira);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
                }

            }



            [HttpPost("Deletar")]
            public IActionResult Deletar([FromBody]Madeira madeira)
            {
                try
                {

                    _madeiraRepository.Remover(madeira);

                    return Json(_madeiraRepository.ObterTodos());


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
                }

            }





            [HttpPost("enviarArquivo")]
            public IActionResult EnviarArquivo()
            {
                try
                {

                    var formFile = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["arquivoEnviado"];

                    var nomeArquivo = formFile.FileName;

                    string novoNomeArquivo = GerarNovoNomeArquivo(nomeArquivo);

                    var pastaArquivos = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\notafiscal\\";


                    //nome final com a extensao 
                    var nomeCompleto = pastaArquivos + novoNomeArquivo;

                    using (var streamArquivo = new FileStream(nomeCompleto, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        formFile.CopyTo(streamArquivo);
                    }

                    return Json(novoNomeArquivo);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
                }

            }

            private static string GerarNovoNomeArquivo(string nomeArquivo)
            {
                var extensao = nomeArquivo.Split(".").Last();

                //var arrayNomeCompacto = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nomeArquivo).Take(10).ToArray();

                //var novoNomeArquivo = new string(arrayNomeCompacto).Replace(" ", "-");

                var novoNomeArquivo = $"{DateTime.Now.Year}{DateTime.Now.Month}{DateTime.Now.Day}_{DateTime.Now.Hour}{DateTime.Now.Minute}{DateTime.Now.Second}{DateTime.Now.Millisecond}.{extensao}";
                return novoNomeArquivo;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt! Para responder a sua pertunta é necessário acrecentar mais informações à mesma. Onde está o backend? Qual base de dados é usada?

Comment: Desculpe minha falta de informações, eu uso o mysql, vou editar a pergunta e colocar o Controller, tem mais algo que tu queira para ajudar? Realmente perdido aqui...

Comment: Pela TAG é possível ver que usa .net core... Indique também a versão, pois pode influenciar na resposta.

Comment: Acho que agora está melhor formulada a pergunta...

Comment: Neste caso, poderia usar o [signalr](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Caso demorem à responder, diria para dar uma olhada [neste tutorial](https://rukshan.dev/2019/05/how-to-notify-your-angular-7-app-using-signalr).

Comment: Vou testar aqui, dai eu já te respondo se deu ou não, vou ter que mudar toda a estrutura do projeto não ? com o exemplo acima, eu tenho 3 projetos Repository, Domain e Web. vou ter que mudar algumas coisas não ?

Comment: recomendo usar websockets

Comment: Desculpe amigo, eu nunca usei websocket, como eu faria? Poderia me dar um norte?

Answer (score -1):

Nesse seu caso, a solução parte pela parte da API.

Teria que implementar um websocket para isso, que poderia ser o signalr.

Da uma olhada nessa documentação.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1